# Android TV: how to press Back button just one time to back to calling intent on YouTube v2.00.17 update

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, android-tv

I used to apply the following suggestion for a new YouTube intent.

[Android TV embedded youtube 1080p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716694/android-tv-embedded-youtube-1080p)

```
String videoId = "dQw4w9WgXcQ";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + videoId));
    intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen", true);
    intent.putExtra("finish_on_ended", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

For YouTube v1.3.11, it is OK to press Back button of remote control 1 time to back to calling intent, but after YouTube updated to v2.00.17. I will meet:

1. After enter new YouTube intent, one message box shows "you are signed out"
   .
2. Pressing Back button, one dialog shows "Are you sure you want to exit YouTube?"
3. However, there is no way to really exit from this
       time on, even I keep pressing Back and selecting EXIT.

Then I try to mark the putExtra commands as below:

```
String videoId = "dQw4w9WgXcQ";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + videoId));
    //intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen", true);
    //intent.putExtra("finish_on_ended", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

New YouTube intent becomes normal, but I need to press Back **3** times to back to calling intent.

On YouTube v2.00.17, is it possible to press Back just **1** time to back? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is of help but [Tasks and Back Stack guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html) seems relevant to your ordeal as it discuess how Android manages the use of Back button to go back to previous tasks.